FastAPI - passing an input to a LangGraph model and getting an output in JSON/HTML
I have the following LangGraph code. I can't seem to integrate it with FastAPI correctly. I want to send to the graph an input which is defined in the inp function, pass it through a langgraph workflow and then return the output in FastAPI.
I can go to the playground and input some text: http://0.0.0.0:5043/generate/playground/
I get the following output:
{
  "node_1": "{'question': ['helo']} Hi ",
  "node_2": "{'question': ['helo']} Hi there"
}

However, when I go to the docs http://0.0.0.0:5043/docs - I click "Try it out" and I can't see where I can input anything.

The overall objective is to pass a HTML search box, pass it through langgraph and display a HTML output.
Additionally, I am a little unsure on the code since I am using add_routes but in the documentation They use async functions and app.get. How can I replace the add_routes and define the pages using app.get/app.post?
@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
async def read_item(item_id):
    return {"item_id": item_id}

Code:
from langgraph.graph import Graph
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn
from langserve import add_routes
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnableLambda


workflow = Graph()


def function_1(input_1):
    return str(input_1) + " Hi "

def function_2(input_2):
    return input_2 + "there"

workflow = Graph()

workflow.add_node("node_1", function_1)
workflow.add_node("node_2", function_2)

workflow.add_edge('node_1', 'node_2')

workflow.set_entry_point("node_1")
workflow.set_finish_point("node_2")

app_graph = workflow.compile()

def inp(question: str) -> dict:
    return {"question": list({question})}

################################################################################

def out(value: dict):
    result = value
    return result

final_chain = RunnableLambda(inp) | app_graph | RunnableLambda(out)

fastapi_app = FastAPI()

add_routes(fastapi_app, final_chain, path = "/generate")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(fastapi_app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5043)
    
#     # http://localhost:5043/openai/playground/
    
################################################################################



However, when I go to the docs http://0.0.0.0:5043/docs - I click "Try it out" and I can't see where I can input anything.

If you want your route to accept input, you need to define a function that accepts either query parameters or a request body or form data.
Here's an example api that simulates a "Magic 8-ball"; it accepts either query parameters on a GET request or a JSON request body on a POST request:
import random
import fastapi
import pydantic


class Question(pydantic.BaseModel):
    question: str


class Answer(pydantic.BaseModel):
    question: Question
    answer: str


Answers = [
    "It is certain",
    "It is decidedly so",
    "Without a doubt",
    "Yes definitely",
    "You may rely on it",
    "As I see it, yes",
    "Most likely",
    "Outlook good",
    "Yes",
    "Signs point to yes",
    "Reply hazy, try again",
    "Ask again later",
    "Better not tell you now",
    "Cannot predict now",
    "Concentrate and ask again",
    "Don't count on it",
    "My reply is no",
    "My sources say no",
    "Outlook not so good",
    "Very doubtful",
]

app = fastapi.FastAPI()


@app.post("/generate")
def generate(question: Question) -> Answer:
    answer = random.choice(Answers)
    return Answer(question=question, answer=answer)


@app.get("/generate")
def generate_get(question: str) -> Answer:
    answer = random.choice(Answers)
    return Answer(question=Question(question=question), answer=answer)

If we visit /docs for this application and click the "Try it out" button for our /generate endpoint, we see that there is now a "request body" field:

If we enter a question (e.g., "Is this a good answer?") and click "Execute", we get a response (and an example curl cli):

Using curl, we can demonstrate a POST request:
curl -X 'POST' 'http://localhost:8000/generate' \
  -H content-type:application/json \
  -d '{"question": "Is this code working?"}'

And a GET request:
curl 'http://localhost:8000/generate?question=Is+this+code+working%3F'


To turn this into a web application with a user-facing interface, you would need to create the necessary HTML and form and possibly some javascript to handle the form submission and response.
If you weren't looking for an API, you could do something similar using form data and have fastapi directly return an HTML response.


I am finding it difficult how I can pass the final_chain langgraph

I am completely unfamiliar with the modules you are working with (langgraph, langserve, etc), but taking a very brief look at the docs, maybe something like this?
import fastapi
import pydantic

from langgraph.graph import Graph
from langserve import add_routes
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnableLambda


class Question(pydantic.BaseModel):
    question: str


class Answer(pydantic.BaseModel):
    question: Question
    answer: str


def function_1(input_1):
    return str(input_1) + " Hi "


def function_2(input_2):
    return input_2 + "there"


workflow = Graph()

workflow.add_node("node_1", function_1)
workflow.add_node("node_2", function_2)

workflow.add_edge("node_1", "node_2")

workflow.set_entry_point("node_1")
workflow.set_finish_point("node_2")

app_graph = workflow.compile()


def inp(question: str) -> dict:
    return {"question": list({question})}


def out(value: dict):
    result = value
    return result


final_chain = RunnableLambda(inp) | app_graph | RunnableLambda(out)

app = fastapi.FastAPI()


@app.post("/generate")
def generate(question: Question) -> Answer:
    answer = final_chain.invoke(question.question)
    return Answer(question=question, answer=answer)

If we call the above endpoint like this:
curl -X 'POST' 'http://localhost:8000/generate' \
  -H content-type:application/json \
  -d '{"question": "Is this code working?"}'

We get the response:
{
  "question": {
    "question": "Is this code working?"
  },
  "answer": "{'question': ['Is this code working?']} Hi there"
}


Thanks for your explanation! Its becoming more clear. I have tried to incorporate your example into my model. I am finding it difficult how I can pass the final_chain langgraph app to the @app.post(/"generate") def generate... function. Simply applying @fastapi_app.post("/generate") def generate(final_chain):     return final_chain  doesn't work.

See my update, where I attempt to demonstrate one way of doing that, with the caveat that I am completely unfamiliar with the modules you're using.

This is working great! In the /generate/playground I can pass in text and it is able to pass it in directly to langgraph. However when I create a basic HTML search box it no longer works. I would like to use something like app.get and `app.post.

This code assumes a JSON request body; if you're posting from an HTML form, you would need instead to handle a form request. The fastapi documentation has a section on exactly that topic.
